# How can we do point-in-time recovery in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

How we can do Point in time recovery in Cassandra.
Can anyone please provide the step by step process.

Answer (score 1):

There are a total fo 3 layers to how one could take backups with C*.

C* has a dual write concept. Data is written to a commitlog (on disk) + memtable (in the memory) for durability purposes.

1. Snapshot - a hardlink/copy on the C* node itself from what's available in the data directory (usually `data_file_directories` config in `cassandra.yaml` file) for a given ks/tbl combination. This will have all the SSTables for that ks/tbl combination at that point when the snapshot (`nodetool snapshot`) is taken. Let's say we take this every 4 hrs.
2. Incremental - a hardlink/copy to a particular SSTable. This will be the same time when the original sstable data is written. Let's say we take this each 1hr.
3. Commitlog - a copy of the individual commitlog file(s). This will ensure transaction level restoration.

All these are to be taken at each node within the cluster.

During restoration:

- Load back the **LATEST** snapshot file(s)
- Also load the incremental backups that was taken *AFTER* the latest snapshot
- load all the commitlog archives from **after** the latest point in time covered by sstables. Point In Time Restore (PITR) requires a cluster restart of all the nodes so that they can catchup with the commitlog backups.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very large scope to discuss in a single Stack Exchange post and it will be impossible to document all the steps here so I'll just go through the main points.

In order to perform a point-in-time restore, you will need the following:

- [Cassandra snapshot](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/managing/operating/backups.html#snapshots) - equivalent of a full, cold database backup
- [incremental backups](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/managing/operating/backups.html#incremental-backups) - copies of SSTables since the last snapshot
- [commitlog archives](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/managing/configuration/cass_cl_archive_file.html) - copies of commit logs since last incremental backup

BEFORE restoring the data:

- Shutdown all clients/apps.
- Truncate target tables so they don't contain any data.
- Shutdown Cassandra.

The high-level steps for restoring a database to its state at time `t`:

1. Restore the last available snapshot just before time `t`.
2. Recover all the incremental backups taken between the snapshot and time `t`.
3. Restore the commit logs from the archives that were created between the last recovered incremental backup and time `t`.

Be advised that performing a full database recovery is NOT advisable in production systems and should instead be done on a completely separate cluster to minimise the risk of data loss in production. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Erick